# How to give file level rights with SVN server

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, rights

I am currently using SVN for Source Control (Visual SVN server + tortoise SVN) and we are starting a new project in a large team.

I was wondering how to give commit rights on specific files or folder to a particular user.
We have given responsibilities for different modules to different developers, and management was wondering if it is possible to restrict a developer to commit to only his module.

I saw that a comment to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991788/what-source-control-systems-have-file-level-permissions/991799#991799) mentions that it is possible with Visual SVN, but I haven't been able to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subversion provides you the option to use path based authorization. That means, you may configure it that users have read, read-write or no access rights to read and write files in a specific directory. This is done on a per-repository base.

The following resources will help you find your way:

- [VisualSVN Server: Understand Access Rights](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00033/)
- [Path based Authorization in Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz)

The first one is very concrete and tells you the rules in the context of VisualSVN Server, the second one is more abstract, but gives you complete background and explanation (and some discussion why restricting developers is no good idea at all).

One final remark: Are you sure that you will never ever need the right to change code in other modules? Refactoring, errors that hinder yourself to do the job, ...?